# How to call java code from Go without invoking the JVM for every call?

Tags: java, go

Is it possible (and if so, what is the recommended way) to call java code from [Go](http://golang.org), without the need to start the JVM for every function call?

I.e, is there any equivalent to the jpype solution for python, which lets you start the JVM once, and then import java classes and call them, using the already started up JVM?

Comment: Have found it now: NailGun: http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/ Quote: "Nailgun is a client, protocol, and server for running Java programs from the command line without incurring the JVM startup overhead ..."

Answer (score 9):

Use [cgo](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) to call into C code that creates a JVM instance using the [JNI invocation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html), and call into Java code using the JNI interface.  As goroutines can technically switch between native threads, you'll probably have to be very careful about testing, attaching and detaching threads to the JVM upon entry and exit from Go code and/or supplement with use of a native threads library like pthreads.

Answer (score 5):

Bundle your java code in a "server" and call it with RPC like "rest/soap/thrift" and keep the server running. I don't know of any system that automate this for you though.

Comment: A useful packaging for Java server-side apps is provided via Dropwizard, http://dropwizard.codahale.com/, which bundles Jetty, Jackson and Jersey to produce high-performance REST-ful web services in Java. You build a 'fat' jar that includes its own webserver and everything, then call its services over REST/HTTP. Starting the service only requires starting the JVM once, which you can do from Go.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, skyde and @Rick-777. I guess REST calls come at some cost though? I like how java calls in JPype as at least sub-millisecond ... will a REST http service manage that?

Comment: Sorry, no chance. If you need that fast level of latency, you'd probably want to investigate using a bespoke protocol over a Unix socket. This approach would allow you to use a textual marshalling such as JSON initially, with a view to optimising that to a binary protocol should it be needed.

Comment: you can use GRPC over unix socket. https://github.com/Ja7ad/grpc-unix-socket

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Java management class in Java which is capable of talking to your Go program, and which you run once and will make the appropriate calls to other Java code when your Go program asks for them.

Comment: You can use any type of interprocess communication. If your Go program starts up the Java program, you can use exec.Command http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/  to run java -jar, and read and write to the Stdin and Stdout, and in the java program read and write to System.in and System.out